# Current Mirroring

Tags: current-mirror

Simply put, would this work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3vdSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or, something like it? If not, could someone explain why?

*This is for a couple of LEDs, and a motor.

**Edit:**

So, more like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvXvBv.png)</sup>

**Edit:**

I was thinking of something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fudDso.png)</sup>

Apparently, the schematics program has no rotary switches. Please assume the 3 toggles are one rotary switch.

**Edit:** forgot to change the 9V to 1.5V in schematic program, so I just fixed that.

**Edit:** Would a JFET Constant-current diode work? I mean, efficiently?
Also, I did a quick search, and I can't really find much on how the JFET Constant-current diode works. Something about saturation, but I don't know why the resistor is there or anything.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOkU5C.png)</sup>
Also, does anyone know how to set the size of the CircuitLab schematics?

Comment: For a current mirror to work both transistors must share the same ground.  Ideally, they would be built on the same substrate to take advantage of the matching provided by being on the same piece of silicon.  Your reference current on the left will not be 1A since there can't be zero volts across the FET.  Otherwise, the basic FET current mirror idea is OK.

Comment: CoilKid: Did you run the simulator?

Comment: @EMFields Simulator?

Comment: @EMFields Ah, NVM. Found what you meant.

Comment: You want the load in the drain side, not the source.  The voltage across the left FET will be somewhat above the threshold voltage of the FET so you should adjust the resistor accordingly (to get your desired current.)  If you're shooting for 1A and your FET has a 3V threshold you will be dissipating 3+ watts in the FET, meaning they will both likely need big heatsinks.  You might be better off with a switch mode current regulator.  It will be smaller and more efficient.

Comment: What do you really want to accomplish? What is the question behind this question?

Comment: Well, the question _is_ the question. The last schematic was what I intended to build. I just wanted to know if it would work/work well. Since it is very inefficient, I'm thinking I'm going to have to find something else.

Comment: The general idea behind it, is: The load has the same current as the reference current, and the reference current can change to preset values. Thereby changing the current of the (Potentially **much**) larger battery powering the load.

Comment: CoilKid, a non integrated current mirror will not work at all. There is no way. That's what amplifiers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBDJlz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You want the gate to source voltage on both transistors equal, that is accomplished by connecting both source's to the same ground, and without a load in between.

The current through M2 will always be different than through M1, becuase of tolerances between two physically independent transistors. Depending on the MOSFET type, you'll need a certain voltage between gate and source to get it conducting. This means that you won't get 1A in either of the two circuits. Say V(GS) = 3V for a drain current of 1A (check the datasheet for an accurate value), then you want a resistor of \$R_1 = \dfrac{V_{R_1}}{I} = \dfrac{9-3}{1} = 6 \Omega\$

Comment: @CoilKid Do notice that you are buring double amount of power, efficiency is alway lower than 50%! Both left half and right half burn about the same power and only the right half is actually efficient.

Comment: Huh... I don't suppose there would be a way to make it more efficient?

Comment: @CoilKid Not with a current *mirror* where both sides use the same supply voltage.

Comment: Well, I was aiming for something slightly different than the schematic I have... I can probably add it, but I doubt its any better then the one I have drawn. I don't suppose anyone here knows of a more efficient way to do what I'm going to draw? :/ Also, thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the `?V` on the right hand side, that might change efficiency but you are still burning a fair amount of power on the left side. (9V × 1A = 9W)

Comment: If you just want to supply a load with a constant current independent of the supply voltage, a switch mode current regulator will be way more efficient.  Something along the lines of this part: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3404.pdf

Comment: Okay, I changed the diagram so show what I had intended to do.

Comment: If you want to use a low voltage on the left side, you'll need a very low threshold FET, and you'll get a lot of variation with temperature.  If you're building more than one of these you'll get huge variation in the load current due to differences in Vt and differences in matching between the two transistors.

Comment: I was thinking just one. But as it was pointed out, it would be inefficient. I probably am gonna have to go work something else out.

Comment: @CoilKid  Research a configuration like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source#mediaviewer/File:Const_cur_src_111.svg

Comment: Any websites that you know of explaining that? I saw it on Wikipedia but, as I am still fairly new to EE, I didn't fully understand it.

Comment: Google for: BJT current source. Then click images and look at the pages that discuss similar circuits. It is a pretty basic circuit, you'll find it explained in many places. Or you can ask a current source specific question  here of coourse. Here is another common circuit: http://www.cunningturtle.com/wiki/index.php?title=BJT_LED_Current_Source (although they confuse gate and base on that page)